# openlayers, error compression with YUI

Tags: javascript, yui, openlayers

I have an issue when i tried to compress OpenLayers.js 2.10 with YUI 2.4.2 (the default one, not custom build). Already download the new package from OL site even i use hosted version of their js located here:
[OpenLayers Hosted](http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js)

The problem was almost every feature broken except for loading map (i use google as map provider), while in past (OL 2.8) i have successful attempt.

So anyone has solution for this? Or maybe willing to share the already successful compressed version?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.openlayers.user/17193

FTA:

> I'm not sure if this is relevant to the YUI compressor, but I found that the JSMin process from the minify project would fail for files that contain lines that start with a '/' character. Specifically, see: http://code.google.com/p/minify/issues/detail?id=205
>
> I specifically had to modify the file XYZ.js (or the corresponding code in a single-file build), and removed the carriage returns in the lines that had slashes at the start. After that, the minify process worked fine. Maybe you'll have similar luck with YUI compressor...otherwise, you may have to try to manully narrow-down the specific parts of the OpenLayers code that's tripping up YUI.

Failing that, the problem might be that single vs. multi file build. See here: http://docs.openlayers.org/library/deploying.html#single-file-build